# "Content type 'image/jpeg' not supported for bodyType=org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile" in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I am using `@RequestPart` annotation to upload some parameters and an image file.

But I am getting below error

```
Content type 'image/jpeg' not supported for bodyType=org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile
```

Below is my code snippet. If I skip the file part while firing the HTTP POST Request. It's working fine.

Only during the passing file. I am getting the error.

```
@PostMapping(value = "document/uploadFile", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public void  uploadFile(@RequestPart(value = "name", required = true) String name,
                        @RequestPart(value = "fileType", required = true) String fileType,
                        @RequestPart(value = "file",required = false) MultipartFile file) 
                        {
                            ..logic to pick the data using POJO
                        }
```

application.yaml

```
## MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
# Enable multipart uploads
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      # Threshold after which files are written to disk.
      file-size-threshold : 2KB
      # Max file size.
      max-file-size: 10MB
      # Max Request Size
      max-request-size : 20MB
```

HTTP Generated Code

```
POST /document/uploadFile HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8026
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

xyz
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileType"

jpeg
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="/C:/Users/XYZ/Pictures/Test.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

(data)
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

Input from POSTMAN

[image: Postman Body]

[image: Postman Header]

Error in Postman

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-01-09T11:17:49.398+0000",
    "path": "/document/uploadFile",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'image/jpeg' not supported for bodyType=org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile"
}
```

Comment: You don't really need the `consumes` so you can remove that. How are you posting the data/form to this controller? Please add that to your question.

Comment: The issue is resolved after adding **spring-boot-starter-web** in maven dependency

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that is the problem but you're missing a parenthesis here at the end **consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}**

In any case with your current code it should work flawlessly, I made a local test so probably your problems lies in how you perform the request.

Be sure to add this as a RequestHeader in your rest client: **Content-Type: multipart/form-data**, or in case you are using a form you need to add it like so:

```
<form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file"/> 
  <input type="name" name="name"/> 
  <input type="fileType" name="fileType"/> 
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```